# yii2 run cron job in lsphp

Tags: yii2, cron, easyapache-4

I am working on yii2 Advance.

My hosting provider has upgraded the server to Easyapache 4 which run lsphp. For this they recomend to below line in htaccess.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-lsphp .html
```

But we do not have the htaccess file in console folder which manage the cron jobs

while I run the console cron job as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /path/public_html/yii test/mail
```

Comment: Why do you want to run console commands with lsphp?

Comment: @rob006 because that is how the cronjobs are run in yii2 php framwork.

Comment: Cron commands are usually run by *console* PHP. It is still not clear why you want to use webserver PHP to run console command.

Comment: I edited the question. I do run the cron job as console command but it dont run after the server been changed to lsphp

Comment: You need to ask your hosting about path to php-cli binary.